# Fail to run docker on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to learn Kubernetes so I've deploy a single-node-cluster of Kubernetes 1.3.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 server.

When I try to run a docker image `nginx` I get the error message `Failed to start with docker id [id-removed] with error: API error (400): {"message":"starting container with HostConfig was deprecated since v1.10 and removed in v1.12"}`

`kubectl version` output:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"0", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v0.19.3", GitCommit:"3103c8ca0f24514bc39b6e2b7d909bbf46af8d11", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"0", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v0.19.3", GitCommit:"3103c8ca0f24514bc39b6e2b7d909bbf46af8d11", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

`dockr --version` output

```
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e
```

Comment: As workaround I've revert back to Docker-1.11 by `apt-get remove docker-engine` and `apt-get install docker-engine=1.11.0-0~trusty`

Comment: Try minikube. Designed for setting up dev environments: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `kubectl version` output, you are running v0.19.3 kubernetes, which is not compatible with docker v1.12. You may want to re-build/re-deploy a newer version of kuberentes.

The version you wanted to run, "v1.3.5" should be compatible with docker v1.12.

Comment: My mistake, I thought I've download newer version but it was very old one